# java problem about ResultSet

Tags: java

I want to merge two Resultset Object into third one.

If you have any idea then reply..

vipul

Comment: Most likely you'll want to handle this with a UNION or JOIN in the SQL used to create the ResultSets.

Answer (score 1):

You can't merge `ResultSet`s directly. You have two options:

1. Create a new class that effectively combines the results; or
2. If the queries have the same type and number of columns and come from the same database you can `UNION` or (preferably) `UNION ALL` them so they come back in one `ResultSet`.

To clarify (1) a `ResultSet` is effectively a cursor. A certain number of results will be loaded but the rest won't be until you progress to them. How do you want to combine them? One after the other? Sorted in some way? Basically you'd have to do that yourself but looping through multiple `ResultSet`s is a small piece of code.

Comment: Friend  first ResultSet contain 3 rows and 2nd resultSet contain minimum 20 rows. then say me how combine two Rs with creating new class

Answer (score 1):

ResultSet is an interface, so you are free to implement it however you want. In your case, you could create a class that implemented ResultSet, but had a constructor that took two other ResultSets. Then implement each method to delegate to either the first ResultSet or the second. For example, the first() method would call rs1.first(), while last() would call rs2.last(). With next(), you'd have to be clever and call rs1.next() until rs1 ran out of rows, then switch to rs2. You'd have to keep track which of the two ResultSets was "current" for the next() calls.